# How can validation users input in integers?

Tags: java, validation, integer

I'm trying to validate choice and quantity. I only create 5 choices for the user to enter and I don't want them to enter any String/Char type or any number higher than 5.

```
System.out.print("Please enter the assigned number of the item sold: "); 
    choice = display.nextInt();
switch(choice){ 
            case 1:
                price=one; 
                break;
            case 2:
                price=two;
                break; 
            case 3:
                price=three;
                break; 
            case 4:
                price=four;
                break; 
            case 5:
                price=five;
                break;

    } // end of switch case
```

For quantity, there's no limit but I don't want the user to enter String/Char type.

```
System.out.print("Please enter the quantity of the item sold: "); 
    quantity = display.nextInt();
```

How can it be done?

Comment: `nextInt` only accept numbers

Comment: how can I display an error? if they enter a String/Char type.

Comment: use next instead of nextInt and check if it is a number or anything else

Answer (score 0):

Add a `default` case to your switch and add a looping mechanism

```
boolean keepAsking = true;
while(keepAsking) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the assigned number of the item sold: "); 
    int choice = display.nextInt();
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            // stuff
            keepAsking = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            // stuff
            keepAsking = false;
            break;
        case 3:
            // stuff
            keepAsking = false;
            break;
        case 4:
            // stuff
            keepAsking = false;
            break;
        case 5:
            // stuff
            keepAsking = false;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please use 1-5")
            keepAsking = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the program will end if the user enters a Char/String type. How can I validate that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parseInt function of the Integer library and wrap it in a try/catch to validate if a value is a number.

```
try {
int x = Integer.parseInt(choice);
 // put your switch statement here and it will only be executed if choice can be parsed as an int
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
// put error-handling or another action here for when it's not an int
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error error: cannot find symbol
        int x = Integer.parsetInt(quantity);
                       ^
  symbol:   method parsetInt(int)
  location: class Integer

Comment: From the error you posted it seems like you misspelled the method name:
  " cannot find symbol int x = Integer.parse**t**Int(quantity); ^ symbol: method 
  parse**t**Int(int) location: class Integer "

(You have an extra t after the word parse))

---- Sorry! My Bad! I misspelled it in the example. Going to edit my original answer now

Answer (score 0):

use a `do { ... }while(condition);` loop to get user input at least once and keep looping while condition is false. See example below. I have added some code which i found in your old/other questions:

```
    float one = 244.50f, two = 125.75f, three = 323.33f, four = 46.29f, five = 3323.65f, price; 
    int choice = 0, quantity = 0, yn;
    Scanner display = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter the assigned number of the item sold: "); 
        String ch = display.next();
        try{
            choice = Integer.parseInt(ch);
            if(choice > 5){
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Only numbers 1 - 5 are valid!");  
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Only numbers 1 - 5 are valid!");                 
        }
    }while(choice == 0 || choice > 5);

    switch(choice){ 
        case 1:
            price=one; 
            break;
        case 2:
            price=two;
            break; 
        case 3:
            price=three;
            break; 
        case 4:
            price=four;
            break; 
        case 5:
            price=five;
            break;
    }

    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter the quantity of the item sold: "); 
        String ch = display.next();
        try{
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(ch);
            if(quantity < 1){
                System.out.println("Invalid input. quantity should be >= 1");  
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Only numbers allowed");                 
        }
    }while(quantity < 1);
}
```